# jQuery form validation, form inputs with name like this[]

Tags: jquery, html, validation

It is possible to use jQuery to validate form inputs like these?

```
<input type='text' name='amount[]' size='1' />
<input type='text' name='amount[]' size='1' />
<input type='text' name='amount[]' size='1' />
```

Or maybe there is some alternative?

Found the solution - http://www.codeboss.in/web-funda/2009/05/27/jquery-validation-for-array-of-input-elements/

Comment: I'd be genuinely surprised if the jQuery [Validation](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation) plugin didn't handle these already, so may be worth a try.

Comment: That style of naming should be reserved for radio button groups. What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: I'm trying to make a shopping cart, using names like this because there is different number of inputs all the time, 1 input per item.

Comment: @JayBlanchard — No, it shouldn't. In fact, that style of naming isn't useful for radio groups since only one element in a group can be checked (and the point of the `[]` syntax is to get PHP to present the data as an array instead of dropping all but one value on the floor).

Comment: @user1093555 — jQuery has no built in validation functionality. Do you have some reason to think that you can't write JavaScript to validate that HTML using jQuery?

Comment: Actually Quentin I mis-typed. I was thinking checkbox groups.

Answer (score 0):

Try This

```
    <input type='text' name='amount[]' size='1' id="id1" />
    <input type='text' name='amount[]' size='1' id="id2"/>
    <input type='text' name='amount[]' size='1' id="id3"/>
```

and validate using id

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
​$("input[name='amount[]']").each(function(i, item){
    // Do your validation here..
    // You can use $(this) to refer to the element
});​​​​​​​​
```

Comment: Sry I'm new to jquery, how exacly i can use it ?
Curently i got this code
`code`
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#cartform").validate({
        errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
            error.appendTo(element.next());
        }
    });
});

<input type='text' name='amount[]' size='1' value='<?php echo $count; ?>' class='required' />

Comment: Have you read the [documentation](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation)? What is it you don't understand?

Comment: This plugin work perfect for normal inputs with an unique names, but i need to validate inputs with a names like this[], i have different number of form inputs all the time.

Comment: Did you have a look at ManseUK's answer?

Answer (score 0):

use index in jquery like this :

```
 $('input').eq(0).bind('change keyup',function(){ ... });
```

or use following code for second input box :

```
 $('input').eq(1).bind('change keyup',function(){ ... });
```

or this one for third input box :

```
 $('input').eq(2).bind('change keyup',function(){ ... });
```